# What does "thou art come unto a feast of death" mean?

Tags: meaning, early-modern-english

I came upon this sentence while reading the narrow road to the deep north. I knew it's from Shakespeare but can't understand.

> Thou art come unto a feast of death

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means "You have come to a feast of death."

In earlier forms of English, we used the auxiliary verb *be* with some verbs, including *come*. The word *art* is the second-person singular form of *be*.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Flanagan wants us to understand that the main character, Dorrigo Evans, can understand his own experience on the Burma railway as a 'feast of death.' There are many dishes served on the Line?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Many books and movies are named after quotes from Shakespeare and many authors quote him. Could you explain why this is an answer to the question. I don't think there were many feasts for the enslaved POW workers on the Thai-Burma railway. In fact starvation was one of the main causes of death, along with cholera.

Answer (score 1):

> But, O malignant and ill-boding stars! Now **thou art come unto a
>   feast of death**, A terrible and unavoided danger: Therefore, dear
>   boy, mount on my swiftest horse; And I'll direct thee how thou shalt
>   escape By sudden flight: come, dally not, be gone.
>
> King Henry VI Part 1.  Act 4. Scene V

The above shows some of the context. I presume that in a previous part of the play, many people have been killed in a battle. (to be researched)

Death has had a feast because of all the fatalities.